# SQL Server Endpoint - Which endpoint used to connect locally to the server?

Tags: sql-server, endpoint

I can create a new T-SQL endpoint 'xyz' for example which will immediately drop accessing to SQL Server for any remote logins since once T-SQL endpoint created the 'public' server role will lose its grant permission to [TSQL default TCP] endpoint which is the default endpoint used to connect remotely to the server.

At the same time the newly create 'xyz' endpoint must have a grant access to let remote logins to access the server. all that is understood.

My question is, which endpoint controls the local access to SQL Server? Except of course 'Dedicated admin connection' which is dedicated endpoint for SQL Server admins only, as its name implies.

Searching google of course, read many articles, tried many things, but so far, I have failed in the end.

Comment: It's not wholly clear what you're after. If you don't want any remote connections, then simply firewall the default TCP/IP endpoint (port 1433); this is much more secure than messing with T-SQL permissions, especially if you're going to deviate from the defaults.

Comment: The point here is not using firewall, but for deep understanding about SQL engine, and how it is work.
mastering SQL Endpoint, will lead for deeper understand and crafting your skills as a DBA.